# ArcGIS APi JS 3.28, panTo is not a function

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I'm working with ArcGIS js-API 3.28 and Angular 7.
I have this code and works well:

The constructor of a map:

```
constructMap(opts: { container: string, basemap: any, center: any, zoom: number, showAttribution: boolean }): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        loadModules([
            'esri/map',
            'esri/config',
            'dojo/domReady!'
        ]).then(([Map, esriConfig/*, Search ,HomeButton*/]) => {
            esriConfig.defaults.map.zoomDuration = 250;
            esriConfig.defaults.map.zoomRate = 50;
            esriConfig.defaults.map.panDuration = 250; // time in milliseconds, default panDuration: 350
            esriConfig.defaults.map.panRate = 50; // default panRate: 25
            this.map = new Map(opts.container, {
                basemap: opts.basemap,
                center: opts.center,
                zoom: opts.zoom,
                showAttribution: opts.showAttribution
            });
            resolve(this.map);
        });
    });
}
```

And in the Component where I set new centers for each select of the dropdown, I have this code (part of it):

```
loadModules([
    'esri/geometry/Point'
]).then(([lang, Point]) => {
    const my_center = new Point([-99.94867549215655, 20.55088183550196]);
    this.mapa.map.centerAndZoom(my_center, 5);
});
```

I can `centerAndZoom` to my desire point (same with `centerAt`). Also, I can change some config of `pan` like this one:

```
esri.config.defaults.map.panDuration = 1000;
esri.config.defaults.map.panRate = 25;
```

And I can see that slower pan on each point that I move with `centerAt` but when I want to use just `this.mapa.map.panTo(my_center);` I got the error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.mapa.map.panTo is not a function
TypeError: _this.mapa.map.panTo is not a function
```

Why? I don't get why the other methods works ok but not `panTo()`

Comment: What version of the ArcGIS API are you using? Can you share the code you use where `this.mapa.map` is defined?

Comment: Also, I'm really surprised that the above `loadModules()` code works since you only require one module but your callback expects `[lang, Point]`.

Comment: @TomWayson I'm using angular, in the constructor of the Map component other modules al already loaded. I will put the entire code in the question now as an Edit.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using version 3.x of the ArcGIS API and in that version [the Map class does not have `panTo` method](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#methods).

Comment: I use 3.28, https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_navigation.html, that's mentioned `panTo()` check in the end of the file.

Comment: the ArcGIS documentation documentation is not always up to date. See here (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#methods) for a list of the methods on the Map object. And see here (https://codepen.io/iamthepieman/pen/rENbaN) for proof